# fiber optic PON cable to ethernet

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, switch, fiber

I have a fiber optic internet connection that connects to Huawei EchoLife HG8247H Router via PON port, it has one public IP
my question is that can I configure that router to act like a switch so that I can get the Public IP to my Server because router acts like an access point and it changes the network to 192.168.100.1
or other question is: is there a switch that has two PON ports for input and output and Ethernet ports as well? So I can connect the PON to router from switch and Ethernet to Server directly from Switch and NOT from router?

Comment: [How to open a port on the Huawei HG8247H](https://portforward.com/huawei/hg8247h/)

Comment: @DavidPostill that article is about port-forwarding, does that mean I can forward the Public IP that is different from the network WLAN created? for example router network is 192.168.100.1 and my Public IP is 185.131.x.x

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is how you access an inside service from outside. You forward the **port** for the service, eg `80` for a web server.